# what does the command awk -F/ mean?

Tags: linux, grep

In more detail, I've been doing an assignment that asks for me to find all files under a directory in all caps, saved in a txt file with no overlapping entries, and said directory looks something like this.

```bash
website.com - - [date/date/date:date:date:date -0400] "GET /elv/HELLO/wave.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 1318
website.com - - [date/date/date:date:date:date -0400] "GET /elv/ball.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 306
```

I tried:

```bash
grep "/elv/" (filename.txt) | awk '{print $7}' |
awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep ^[A-Z] | sort -u > elv.txt
```

I've come to the understanding what

```
grep "/elv/" (filename.txt)

awk '{print $7}'

grep ^[A-Z]

sort -u > elv.txt
```

mean, but i do not understand why the code

```bash
awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

Is then necessary. Is it used to not register the rest of the `$7` past the `/` of `/elv/CAPITALISED_WORD` after the `CAPITALISED_WORD`?

I have tried

```
grep "/elv/" (filename.txt) | awk '{print $7}' |
awk -F/ '{print $3}' | grep ^[A-Z] | sort -u > elv.txt
```

for my initial test, and the result comes in a txt file with all names that are capitalised after `/elv/`.

```
HELLO
(list of other capitalised words)
```

But when I tried

```
grep "/elv/" (filename.txt) | awk '{print $7}' | grep ^[A-Z] |
sort -u > elv.txt
```

The txt file would appear blank.

I would have thought that by putting in the first attempt I made, it would have given a text file that would look like this.

```
HELLO/wave.gif
```

Edited for more clarity

Comment: All the 5 commands can be reduced into one single awk

Comment: May I have an example? My understanding of coding is still very weak, so I wished to ask what the commands meant

Comment: You should edit your question and provide input sample and expected output in text format not an image. `-F/` just splits input records on `/` character.

Comment: My apologies, I was merely unsure how the -F/ function works, let me re-edit the question for it to be clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` that combines 2 grep and 2 awk commands into one:

```bash
awk '/\/elv\// && split($7, a, /\//) && a[3] ~ /^[A-Z]/ {print a[3]}' file |
sort -u

HELLO
```

To answer your question:

```
awk -F/ '{print $3}'
```

Prints 3rd column in a record split by `/`.

**Details about awk command:**

- `/\/elv\//`: If an input line matches text `/elv/`
- `&& split($7, a, /\//)`: and if 7th field can be split by `/`
- `&& a[3] ~ /^[A-Z]/`: and if 3rd field in split array starts with an uppercase letter
- `{print a[3]}`: Print 3rd element of `split` array

Comment: I see, I admit, this is not being taught in my syllabus, since this is also my first time learning of grep. Is it possible to give an explanation what each part does? I am a little bit confused

Comment: Have added an explanation. I would also suggest reading a good awk tutorial, it is very powerful language.

Comment: I admit, the line is very complex for what I'm currently learning, but it does work!